# Adições e Deleções por arquivo num commit

Tags: git, log, diff

Estou usando o comando `git log --stat <commit>` para obter as adições e deleções feitas em um commit.

Ex:

```
commit 1a1a
Author: Gabriel Hardoim
Date: 2018-08-20 20:30:40

arquivo.java    | 3 +++
arquivo.css     | 3 ---

2 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
```

Até aqui tudo bem, mas em casos onde no mesmo arquivo linhas foram adicionadas e removidas ele exibe um número de alterações por arquivo maior que o número de alterações total.

Ex:

```
commit 1a1a
Author: Gabriel Hardoim
Date: 2018-08-20 20:30:40

arquivo.java    | 5 +----
arquivo.css     | 5 ++++-

2 files changed, 5 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
```

Em casos assim:

- Como faço para descobrir quantas adições/deleções foram feitas em cada arquivo?
- Existe algum comando ou flag que possa me ajudar nesse sentido?

> Ps: Quando o número de alterações é muito grande, a quantidade de `+` e `-` ao lado do arquivo não deixa tão claro como nos casos de pequenas alterações.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos entender porque parece que o git *"exibe um número de alterações por arquivo maior que o número de alterações total"*.

Vamos supor que eu tenho um arquivo com 3 linhas:

```
primeira linha do arquivo
segunda linha do arquivo
terceira linha do arquivo
```

Vamos supor também que este é o conteúdo que está no último commit (no meu caso, só tem 1 commit):

```
$  git log --oneline
792eda8 primeiro commit
```

Em seguida eu edito o arquivo, mudando a segunda linha e adicionando uma quarta linha:

```
primeira linha do arquivo
mudando a segunda linha do arquivo, blablabla etc
terceira linha do arquivo
adicionar quarta linha
```

E faço o commit do mesmo:

```
$ git add arq.txt
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in arq.txt.

$ git commit -m "mudar arquivo"
[master d0be287] mudar arquivo
1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

$ git log --oneline
d0be287 mudar arquivo
792eda8 primeiro commit
```

Se usarmos `git log` para ver as alterações, teremos 2 inserções e 1 deleção:

```
$ git log --stat d0be287 -1
commit d0be287ddf28aa910d8fa9d002a609aa8056e357
Author: Fulano de Tal <fulano@teste.com>
Date:   2018-09-12 09:07:34

    mudar arquivo

 arq.txt | 3 ++-
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

E se usarmos `git diff`, podemos ver com mais detalhes as alterações:

```
$ git diff 792eda8 d0be287
diff --git a/arq.txt b/arq.txt
index 7e12196..757a5bd 100644
--- a/arq.txt
+++ b/arq.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 primeira linha do arquivo
-segunda linha do arquivo
+mudando a segunda linha do arquivo, blablabla etc
 terceira linha do arquivo
+adicionar quarta linha
```

No caso, estou vendo a diferença entre os commits `792eda8` e `d0be287`.

Agora repare como é mostrada a alteração na segunda linha. Ele mostra que o trecho `segunda linha do arquivo` foi "removido" (está com `-` na frente), dando lugar a `mudando a segunda linha do arquivo, blablabla etc` (que foi "adicionada", pois está com `+` na frente).

Por isso, embora a alteração tenha sido "editar uma linha", o git considera que foi feita uma inserção e uma deleção.

Já a quarta linha aparece como adicionada (com `+` na frente). Por isso o resultado são 2 inserções e 1 deleção. Pode-se ter um resumo disso com as opções `--stat`, `--shortstat` e `--numstat`, que mostram a mesma informação em formatos diferentes:

```
$ git diff 792eda8 d0be287 --stat
 arq.txt | 3 ++-
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

$ git diff 792eda8 d0be287 --shortstat
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

$ git diff 792eda8 d0be287 --numstat
2       1       arq.txt
```

`--numstat` é a opção mais "compacta", mostrando apenas os números e o nome do arquivo (no caso acima, são 2 inserções e 1 deleção), o que é um bom formato para ser lido por scripts, por exemplo.

---

Mas se você não quer que uma alteração na mesma linha seja contada duas vezes (como uma inserção e uma deleção) e gostaria de saber apenas se uma linha foi modificada, outra opção é usar `--word-diff`, que mostra as diferenças levando em conta as palavras (sendo que "palavras" são delimitadas por espaços):

```
$ git diff 792eda8 d0be287 --word-diff
diff --git a/arq.txt b/arq.txt
index 7e12196..757a5bd 100644
--- a/arq.txt
+++ b/arq.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
primeira linha do arquivo
{+mudando a+} segunda linha do [-arquivo-]{+arquivo, blablabla etc+}
terceira linha do arquivo
{+adicionar quarta linha+}
```

Repare que agora as alterações da segunda linha são mostradas todas em uma única linha, mostrando as palavras que foram adicionadas e removidas.

Você pode ainda usar `--word-diff-regex` para definir uma expressão regular que define o que é uma palavra. No seu caso, você poderia usar `^.*$`, que significa "zero ou mais caracteres (`.*`) do início (`^`) ao fim (`$`) da linha" - ou seja, toda a linha é considerada uma única palavra. O resultado é:

```
$ git diff 792eda8 d0be287 --word-diff-regex="^.*$"
diff --git a/arq.txt b/arq.txt
index 7e12196..757a5bd 100644
--- a/arq.txt
+++ b/arq.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
primeira linha do arquivo
[-segunda linha do arquivo-]{+mudando a segunda linha do arquivo, blablabla etc+}
terceira linha do arquivo
{+adicionar quarta linha+}
```

A segunda linha continua aparecendo como se tivesse uma deleção e uma inserção, mas pelo menos a informação está toda em uma linha só. Com isso, é possível usar `egrep` (caso você esteja usando o bash) para contar somente estas linhas.

```
$ git diff 792eda8 d0be287 --word-diff-regex="^.*$" | egrep -e "^(\[-|\{\+)" -c
2
```

No caso, estou considerando somente as linhas que começam com `[-` ou `{+`. Como eu considero que toda a linha é uma única palavra, isso garante que qualquer linha modificada começará com algum destes caracteres. Em seguida, uso a opção `-c` para retornar a quantidade de linhas (no caso, `2`). Se você não usar a opção `-c`, o retorno são as próprias linhas modificadas:

```
$ git diff 792eda8 d0be287 --word-diff-regex="^.*$" | egrep -e "^(\[-|\{\+)"
[-segunda linha do arquivo-]{+mudando a segunda linha do arquivo, blablabla etc+}
{+adicionar quarta linha+}
```

Também é possível mudar a regex do `egrep` para trazer as modificações separadamente:

- `egrep -e "^\[-.*-\]\{\+"` - linhas que foram modificadas (começam com `[-` e possuem também `{+`)
- `egrep -e "^\[-.*-\]$"` - linhas que foram removidas (começam com `[-` e terminam com `-]`)
- `egrep -e "^\{\+.*\+\}"` - linhas que foram adicionadas (começam com `{+` e terminam com `+}`)

Lembrando que podem haver falsos positivos (caso alguns dos delimitadores `[-`, `{+`, etc façam parte da própria linha).

---

Você também poderia usar `git diff d0be287~` - e nesse caso `d0be287~` significa "o commit anterior a d0be287" (para mais detalhes sobre esta sintaxe, veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2221658) e [aqui](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-rev-parse#_specifying_revisions)). No caso, ele verifica as diferenças entre o commit anterior a `d0be287` e o seu `HEAD` (ou seja, o branch que você está atualmente).